# (Android studio) Como pegar o id de um usuário pelo email dele no Realtime Database (Firebase)

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, realtime-database

Eu gostaria de saber como eu posso pegar um id do meu banco de dados no firebase pelo email.

Por exemplo eu tenho o email teste@teste.com e gostaria de pegar o id dele só pelo email. 
É possivel?

Comment: Olá thiago, sua pergunta está meio vaga, tenta exemplificar. Porque por exemplo se voce adicionar um usuario no firebase ele é atualizado automaticamente e é atualizada em todos os db's dos usuarios. Entap depende de qual a regra de negocio do seu app, o user vai fazer login com o email, nome, telefone, usuario voce que decide.

Comment: Olá, então, eu tenho organizado minha database assim {
  "usuario" : {
    "MTIzQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==" : {
      "email" : "123@gmail.com",
      "id" : "MTIzQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==",
      "idade" : "15",
      "nome" : "Henrique",
    
    },
    "aG1lbmRvbmNhcm9kcmlndWVzQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==" : {
      "email" : "hmendon@gmail.com",
      "id" : "aG1lbmRvbmNhcm9kcmlndWVzQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==",
      "idade" : "20",
      "nome" : "Henrique",
    
    }, Como eu faria para saber qual tem o email 123@gmail.com e pegar o id dele.

Answer (score -1):

Neste caso Thiago, voce pode usar o firebase authentication com alguma plataforma como facebook e google para nao precisar de senha, ou pode incluir o chave senha no seu db.

Para voce fazer um "search" no seu db ele deve estar ordenado, o firebase já te dá todas estas implementacoes, tanto o "search" quanto o "order", na propria pagina do firebase já te da os exemplos necessarios para resolver seu problema, segue o [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data?hl=pt-br). Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Desculpe, mas não achei nada lá que pudesse me ajudar :(

Comment: posta seu codigo no qual faz o request pro db

Comment: Infelizmente tudo que eu tenho é para pegar um valor pelo id, mas eu gostaria de saber como eu posso pegar um id só pelo email, pois eu tenho uma tela de login onde eu queria pegar o email que a pessoa logou e assim exibir algumas informações sobre ela. Eu já tentei com o id dando um getId mas está aparecendo um id que não é do usuario, então eu queria dar meio que uma volta para exibir os dados dela

Comment: Entendi, no caso voce tem que fazer uma query para o seu db e procurar o Child dele, tem a funcao equalTo() que voce procura o valor exato. Infelizmente o tema é bem amplo mesmo, mas vou tentar te guiar pelas referencias, https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#equalTo essa é sobre a funcao com exemplo, mas nesse link https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data voce vai encontrar mais repostas é somente sobre a ordenacao e query do db

Comment: Ok, Obrigado vou tentar isso.